# Spending Limit for Gas

Tags: gnosis-safe

Is it possible to set a spending Limit regarding the amount of Gas a Signer is allowed to use per day?

I tried out the spending limit function and it only restricts the amount of (native) tokens that are allowed to be send

Answer (score 1):

The signers need to pay for gas out of their own wallets, not out of the Safe. So the spending limit does not apply to them.